# Error executing pytorch code AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Variable'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Trying to run pytorch code from github from following repo

https://github.com/jalola/improved-wgan-pytorch

The error is at the following statement in the file gan_train.py

```
   writer.add_scalar('data/disc_cost', disc_cost, iteration)
```

The error is as follows

```
File "/home/anaconda/new_anaconda_3.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/writer.py", line 272, in add_scalar
    self.file_writer.add_summary(scalar(tag, scalar_value), global_step)

  File "/home/anaconda/new_anaconda_3.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/summary.py", line 86, in scalar
    scalar = makenp(scalar)

  File "/home/anaconda/new_anaconda_3.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/x2num.py", line 15, in makenp
    return pytorch_np(x, modality)

  File "/home/anaconda/new_anaconda_3.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/x2num.py", line 24, in pytorch_np
    if isinstance(x, torch.autograd.variable.Variable):
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Variable'
```

Any ideas, I am not very proficient in pytorch. It seems something is wrong with the tensorboard API.

Thanks a lot.

Shan

Comment: Hey, did you solve the problem? If you found a solution it would be great if you could share it!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a version issue, the line:

```
torch.autograd.variable.Variable
```

works with PyTorch `0.3.1` but not with version `0.4.0`, then it throws the same error you have. So I guess you're using version `0.4.0`.

(In version `0.4.0` the classes `Tensor` and `Variable` got merged, so Variables are not needed any longer.)

If so, using version `0.3.1` will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is tensorboardX version error

you need change `torch.autograd.variable.Variable` to `torch.autograd.Variable` in `/home/anaconda/new_anaconda_3.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/x2num.py`
. its works for me.

more info https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboardX/commit/c5189bdb019085841dbfeeb457b1f6682c7dbfbf